# Create dict of substrings from string with unspecified values in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a set of strings that I want to loop through and turn into pandas dataframes. Each string has keywords that I want to turn into columns and the following characters as column values until the next keyword is reached. Only the column keywords will remain the same across all strings.

Below is an example of a string that I would like to parse. Every string will have the keywords (Wilhering Abbey, The buildings, The Rococo) but the text in between them will be different.

```
Wilhering Abbey is a Cistercian monastery in Wilhering in Upper Austria about 8 km from the city of Linz The buildings re-constructed in the 18th century are known for their spectacular Rococo The Rococo style in the German-speaking world This photograph depicts the interior of the church
```

Ideally I would like to end up with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
| Wilhering Abbey |  The buildings                   |   The Rococo style
|:________________|:_________________________________|:______________________________
| is a Cistercian | re-constructed                   |  style in the German-speaking 
| Wilhering in    | in the 18th century are known    |  world This photograph depicts   
| monastery in    | for their spectacular Rococo     |    the interior of the church   
| Upper Austria   |                                  |
| about 8 km from |                                  |
| the city of Linz|                                  |
```

So far I have tried a few techniques, such as the code below but I don't have a lot of experience parsing text, any help is appreciated.

```
result = "Wilhering Abbey is a Cistercian monastery in Wilhering in Upper Austria about 8 km from the city of Linz The buildings re-constructed in the 18th century are known for their spectacular Rococo The Rococo style in the German-speaking world This photograph depicts the interior of the church"

keywords = ['Wilhering Abbey', 'The buildings', 'The Rococo style']
pattern = '|'.join(['(' + i + ')' for i in keywords])
lst = re.split(pattern, result)
```

Comment: This is a side trip, but what are you going to do with this?  pandas wants all columns to be the same length, and you don't really want the column titles to be part of the data.  Column titles should be constants.

Comment: You're right, this may be overcomplicated for nothing. I would be happy with being able to break up the string into substrings that contain key value pairs by specifying the keyword I want to start and stop on but am also having trouble getting that right

Comment: You can use the plain old `.find` method to search for the substrings.  That returns the starting location, and from that you can chop it up.

Comment: Try something like ```pattern = '(%s)' % '|'.join(keywords); lst = re.split(pattern, result); d = dict(zip(lst[1::2], lst[2::2]))```.